# PWM with 12V DC fan on arduino

Tags: arduino, transistors, pid-controller, fan

I am using an Arduino with PWM to control two 12V DC fans....however the fan works at 12V and Arduino at 5V, what kind of circuit do i need to allow this to function to work?

I would imagine that some kind of transistor is needed to allow the Arduino to control the fans but I'm not sure, how this works. I work with software mostly and not hardware or electronics so any help would be amazing.

Thanks Jonny

Comment: If you google: "Arduino fan control" you would find plenty of examples of how to do this. Explain to me why using Google has not occurred to you ?

Comment: Please read the forum rules, the question you posted indicates you did little research.

Comment: Insufficient preliminary research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do, is use a logic-level MOSFET like this:

http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/International-Rectifier/IRLB3034PBF/?qs=9%252bKlkBgLFf0jZeWnRhawEQ%3D%3D&gclid=CjwKEAjwlfO3BRDR4Pj_u-iO2U0SJAD88y1SNqE8wsns_k0eHN65tR4jnr0aCuOUL1P3y6HIFceC6RoCnrPw_wcB

and if your Arduino is one that supports 12V power input, just conect te MOSFET to the same power as the Arduino, else have a separate power supply and onnect the GND of your Aduino to the GND of the 12V supply, and drive the MOSFET and the fan through that. Then just drive the gate of the MOSFET with the PWM pin of your Arduino, and if you hooked it up right, you should get a PWM signal at 2V to the fan. Good luck!